# Getting two Windows boot options after installing the OS on BootCamp

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, dual-boot

I installed Windows 10 on my 2017 MacBook Pro (Intel-based) through [BootCamp](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/boot-camp) and this is what I get at the boot menu after restarting my device:

[image]

Two Windows boot icons.

- The first one starts Windows.
- The second triggers the Windows ISO setup.

I'm looking for a way to delete the second one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** : The 2nd one disappeared after I booted on Mac again & deleted the Windows ISO file selected when using Boot Camp.